# How to detect when the mouse exits the ol.map area

Tags: openlayers-3

I need to know when the mouse (pointer) exits and enters the map area. 
The API only lists 'pointermove' as one option, which stops responding when the mouse is outside the map. How do I detect when the mouse exits and enters the map area?

Comment: Share your code/workaround first.

Comment: map area is just a div container. thus you may use the native js `onmouseout` `onmouseover` methods on your map div.

Comment: So simple - Thanks.